# PHPUnit mock using mock

Tags: php, dependency-injection, mocking, phpunit, unit-testing

I have two class, i want to test it via PHPUnit. 
But something i do wrongly at mocking the stuffs. I want to altering a method what called by the first class.

```
class One {
    private $someVar = null;
    private $abc = null;

    public function Start() {
        if ( null == $this->someVar) {
            $abc = (bool)$this->Helper();
        }

        return $abc;
    }

    public function Helper() {
        return new Two();
    }


}
Class Two {
    public function Check($whateverwhynot) {
        return 1;
    }
}


Class testOne extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testStart() {
        $mockedService = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(
                'Two',
                array('Check')
            )
            ->getMock();

        $mockedService
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('Check')
            ->with('13')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $mock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(
                'One',
                array('Helper'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mock
            ->expects($this->once()) 
            ->method('Helper')
            ->will($this->returnValue($mockedService));

        $result = $mock->Start();
        $this->assertFalse($result);
    }
}
```

And the result is for the `$result` is `NULL`, instead of '`true`'

If I don't use the assert line, i get an error message:

```
F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 13.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) testOne::testStart
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:Check> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Ideas?

Update
 - Environment: PHP 5.4.3x, PHPUnit 3.7.19
 - An important thing: can't modify the original classes (Class One and Class Two)

Comment: PHPUnit works for dependency injection. You need to inject the mocked Two class into One. Also you didn't use the parameters of getMockBuilder method correctly.

Comment: Wherer I use badly the getMockBuilder? 

How can I inject the second mocked class into the first one? I don't found any example or documentation or anything for it, can you drop a link or something please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your mocks wrong.  You are using `$this->getMockBuilder()` which takes only one argument, the name of the class to be mocked.  You seem to be conflating it with `$this->getMock()` that takes multiple.

Change the test to:

```
public function testStart() {
    $mockedService = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Two')
        ->setMethods(array('Check'))
        ->getMock();

    $mockedService
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('Check')
        ->with('13')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('One')
        ->setMethods(array('Helper'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mock
        ->expects($this->once()) 
        ->method('Helper')
        ->will($this->returnValue($mockedService));

    $result = $mock->Start();
    $this->assertFalse($result);
}
```

This isn't a good test because we are needing mock the class that we are testing but you stated that you can't change the classes at all.

Comment: Thanks the help, it's working. In other case the injection also working && yeah, i really use the mockbuilder wrongly. Thanks again!

Comment: It would be better to refactor the class, so that you use Dependency Injection but if you can't change the classes ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use mocks from [ouzo-goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies).

Classes:

```
class One
{
    private $someVar = null;
    private $abc = null;
    private $two;

    public function __construct(Two $two)
    {
        $this->two = $two;
    }

    public function Start()
    {
        if (null == $this->someVar) {
            $abc = (bool)$this->Helper()->Check(1213);
        }

        return $abc;
    }

    public function Helper()
    {
        return $this->two;
    }
}
```

In constructor inject object `Two`, thus you can easily mock this object.

```
class Two
{
    public function Check($whateverwhynot)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And tests:

```
class OneTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldCheckStart()
    {
        //given
        $mock = Mock::create('\Two');
        Mock::when($mock)->Check(Mock::any())->thenReturn(true);

        $one = new One($mock);

        //when
        $start = $one->Start();

        //then
        $this->assertTrue($start);
    }
}
```

Docs for [mocks](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/tests.html#mocking).

Comment: Good point, thanks for it!.... but the main problem is, I can't modify the original One and Two class and can't use any 3rd party lib for testing.